# Select 2 Not working in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://localhost/mytests/js/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://localhost/mytests/js/select2.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#e1").select2();
                $("#e1").select2(
                    {
                        placeholder: "Select a State",
                        allowClear: true
                    });
                $("#e2_2").select2(
                    {
                        placeholder: "Select a State"
                    });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="e1">
        <option value="AL">
            Alabama
        </option>
        <option value="AL">
            Alabama
        </option>
        <option value="AL">
            Alabama
        </option>
        <option value="AL">
            Alabama
        </option>
        <option value="AL">
            Alabama
        </option>

        <option value="WY">
            Wyoming
        </option>
    </select>
</body>
```

the above code is for selecting cities and also being able to search through the options. The link at the top is for adding select2.js and select2.css. this is not working at the moment.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Does your javascript console give you any errors?

Comment: Download jQuery on http://jquery.com/, save to "http://localhost/mytests/js/jquery.js"` on your machine (change the name to jquery.js) and then add <script src="http://localhost/mytests/js/jquery.js"></script> above the other `<script>` tags in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your code working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/2889/) .Refer the fiddle.
Include jquery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://localhost/mytests/js/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://localhost/mytests/js/select2.js">

 $("#e1").select2();
 $("#e1").select2(
   {
     placeholder: "Select a State",
     allowClear: true
   });
 $("#e2_2").select2(
  {
    placeholder: "Select a State"
 });
```